# rails how to pass nested parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a strong parameter like this

> params.require(:survey).permit( option_booleans_attributes: [:id, :survey_id, :topic, :answer])

if I use rails f.input I got parameter like

> "option_booleans_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"answer"=>"true", "id"=>"5"}, "1"=>{"answer"=>"false", "id"=>"6"}, "2"=>{"answer"=>"true", "id"=>"7"}}}

but I need to show option_booleans topic and let user fill answer

> ```
>   <% @survey.option_booleans.each do |question| %>
>     <%= question.topic %><br>
>     <%= radio_button "option_booleans_attributes[]", "answer[#{question.id}]", "true" %>是
>     <%= radio_button "option_booleans_attributes[]", "answer[#{question.id}]", "false" %>否<br>
>   <% end %>
> ```

But I don't know how to generate the 0 1 2 in the parameter..

about my survey.rb

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :option_booleans
accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_booleans

belongs_to :member

end
```

> class OptionBoolean < ActiveRecord::Base
>        belongs_to :survey03

and OptionBoolean have topic:string and answer:boolean

I want to let user see the topic and update the answer

Comment: I am not quite sure by what you mean by 'generate 0 1 2 in the parameter' - do you mean how to access these attroibutes?

Comment: Cuz I use strong params to access, and it can't correspond option_booleans

Comment: Now I use <%= radio_button "option_booleans_attributes[#{question.id}]", "answer", "true" %>
        and access in the back-end params[:option_booleans_attributes].each do |option_id, attributes| to solve but is it a good way? this means I didn't use strong params

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your `survey.rb` model file so we can see exactly what `options_booleans` are - are they question models, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I push it, is it enough?

Comment: there's no issue with your strong parameters code. if it's not working, the problem lies in another part of your app.

Comment: I think cuz <%= radio_button "option_booleans_attributes[]", "answer[#{question.id}]", "true" %> didn't assign to which option_booleans but I don't know how to do that... "1"=>{"answer"=>"false", "id"=>"6"}, I don't know how to generate this "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I use now

> ```
>    <li><% @survey03.option_booleans.each do |question| %>
>    <%= question.topic %><br>
>         <%= radio_button "option_booleans_attributes[#{question.id}]", "answer", "true", :required => true %>
>         <%= radio_button "option_booleans_attributes[#{question.id}]", "answer", "false", :required => true %>
>     <% end %></li>
> ```

and in controller

> 

```
params[:option_booleans_attributes].each do |option_id, attributes|    

if option = OptionBoolean.find_by_id(option_id)
       option.update_attributes(attributes)
    end 
end
```

and I know if I want to generate index just use

> ```
>     <% @survey.option_booleans.each_with_index do |question, index| %>        
>       <%= question.topic %><br>
>       <%= radio_button "option_booleans_attributes[#{index}]", "answer[#{question.id}]", "true" %>
>       <%= radio_button "option_booleans_attributes[#{index}]", "answer[#{question.id}]", "false" %>
>     <% end %>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing several parts of your form:

```
#app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb
def new
   @survey = Survey.new
   @survey.option_booleans.build #-> creates ActiveRecord Object for your form
end

#app/views/surveys/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :option_booleans do |option| %>
       <% @survey.question_booleans.each do |question| %>
           <%= question.topic %>
           <%= f.radio_button "answer[#{question.id}]", "true" %>
           <%= f.radio_button "answer[#{question.id}]", "false" %>
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Although I don't quite understand how your system works

You have a survey with many options, but you're passing new attributes to create new options each time. Surely you'd have `option_booleans` as a join model, with `options` as an independent model, and:

```
#app/models/survery.rb
Class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :option_booleans
    has_many :options, through: :option_booleans
end
```

Comment: I doesn't mean to create new options each time, if I create at the back-end and I want to let user see the option_booleans.topic:string and update option_booleans.answer:boolean.So I think it doesn't need to build in the controller right?

Answer (score 0):

try select options like this:

```
@variable_with_booleans = [true, false]
<%= f.select :param, @variable_with_booleans %>
```

answer to your latest comment:
I don't sure, but try to edit your form

```
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :topic %>
  <% @variable_with_booleans = [true, false] %>
  <%= f.select :answer, @variable_with_booleans %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and edit your strong params in controller,which contains this action

Comment: if I want to show the :topic, how can I add in this code?           I want to show option_booleans.topic and update option_booleans.answer..

Comment: is your topic depends on question boolean?

Comment: yes, option_booleans has two columns, topic(:string) and answer(:boolean)

Comment: So that page is form_for @survey and option_boolean is belongs_to survey, I need to show topic and update answer in this form